# how to increase the progress bar value based on validations

Tags: jquery

Hello i have the code like following..
In this i have validations... i used progress bar also.. for every validation if it is true then the progress bar value should increase by 10..if validation not performed well then the progress bar value should be at the same state..how to achieve this.. plz help me

Thank you

```
$('form').validate({
        rules: {
        name:{
            required:true,
                minlength:5
            },
        psd:{
                required:true,
                    minlength:6
            },
        repsd:{
                required:true,
                equalTo:'#pwd'
                },
        dob:{
                    required:true
                },
        email:{
                required:true,
                    email:true
        },
                address: {
                        required:true
                }
        },
            success:function(label){
                label.text('ok').addClass('valid');
        }
})
```

for progress bar i wrote like this.. ofcourse it is not work as per my desired condition

```
$('#progressdiv').progressbar();
    $('.same').blur(function(){
    $('#progressdiv').progressbar('value', i);
    i=i+10;
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have a jQuery UI CSS. I removed alot of your other code for simplicity.
 HTML

```
<form name="f1" action="post" id="f1">
    <div id="mydiv1">
    <table id="mytab1">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label for="name">UserName</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input class="same" type="text" value="UserName" name="name"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input class="same" type="password" id="pwd" value="password" name="psd"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label for="confirmpsd">Retype password</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input class="same" type="password" value="re-type password" name="repsd" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label for="dob">DateOfBirth</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input class="same" id="date" type="text" value="DD/MM/YYY" name="dob" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label for="HighestEd">Highest qualification</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input class="same" type="text" value="qualification" name="hed"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label for="email">Email-id</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" class="same" value="Email-address" name="email"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label for="email">What you like to receive</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rec_type" class="checkall">Select all</td><tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rec_type">Emails<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rec_type">Notifications<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rec_type">NewLetters<br/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <textarea class="same" rows=7 cols=25 value="Type address" name="adrs"/></textarea>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" id="buttonRegister" value="Register">
    <div id="divPercent">0%</div>
    <div id="progessdiv"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

jQuery

```
    validator = null;
    $(document).ready(function() {

       $(".same").blur(function(){
           updateProgress(validator);
       });

       $('#progessdiv').progressbar({value: 0});
       var validator = $('form').validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                psd: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                },
                repsd: {
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: '#pwd'
                },
                dob: {
                    required: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                address: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            success: function(label) {
                label.text('ok').addClass('valid');
            },
            invalidHandler: function() {
                updateProgress(validator);
            }
        });
    });

function updateProgress(validator){
    var percentage = 0;
    if (validator != null){
        percentage = 100 - (validator.numberOfInvalids() * (100 / $('.same').length));
        $('#progessdiv').progressbar("option", "value", percentage);
        $('#divPercent').text(percentage + "%");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Timothy Here element means what...?

Comment: i use http://jsfiddle.net/. Create an account, save the code. Then give me the link to it.

Comment: i got it. I have removed a lot of other code but there it should be. The website wasn't quite working for me properly, so if you are having troubles i have the code in a txt file and i can post it on this website

Comment: @Timoty... hey here number of fields is undefined.. how to handle it?

Comment: oh sorry. you need to set up a variable which stores how many variables the validator checks. I have changed that answer.

Comment: ya ya.. i kept that variable.. but our intension is when we lose focus on the text box if the input is correct then the progress bar should be increment.. but this code works only if we click on register..

Comment: well its a step forward right. still will be good to have in there anyway. I can't see anything in the jQuery Validator that is the opposite of success (normally it's error but i tried that), so my next thought would be to create event handlers for each field. I will try to get that working now.

Comment: hmmm grt boss. do u have mail id in yahoo or gmail.. i think your frndshp wl increase my maturity in jquery.. if u like please accept my invitation..brother

Comment: udpate....JSFiddle keeps on crashing on me so i can't test it. Tell me how it goes.

Comment: but how i can inform to you without your id.. u meant we can communicate only through the stackoverflow...!